# How to escape forward slash in T-SQL 2005?

Tags: t-sql, dynamic, escaping, slash

I've got this dynamic t-sql:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql =
N'
insert into #t
SELECT
    row_number() over(order by getdate()) as RowNum,
    d.value('''+@baseDateXpath+''', ''datetime'') as basedate,
    pref.query(''.'') as XmlExtract
FROM
    @content.nodes(''/*/*'') AS extract(pref)
CROSS APPLY
    @content.nodes(''//*'') AS datey(d)
WHERE
    pref.value(''.//*[1]'', ''nvarchar(50)'') IS NOT NULL'

exec sp_executesql @sql,
    N'@content xml',
    @anXmlContentStr
```

And it doesn't work because (I think) the escaping of the forward slashes is being mis-interpreted.

How do I write this string so that it will execute properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it just be that you have
 @content.nodes(''//*'') AS datey(d)
instead of
@content.nodes(''//*'') AS date(d)

If not what is the error that you are rec'ng?

Comment: I'm going to mark this answer as correct, because I have to mark something, but no, I don't think that's what it was. It just started working, indisputably, a little later - so it could have been data - but I've removed the entire thing and redesigned the structure, which is better than doing dynamic SQL, of course.

Comment: @Matt W: Please don't feel that you have to mark something. If this answer doesn't answer your question, then it doesn't help anyone for you to mark it as the answer.